# How to force interface key of certain enum type?

Tags: typescript, enums, interface, typescript2.0

Considering this interface:

```
export interface Vehicle<E> {
 [key: E]: {
   title: string
 }
}
```

And these enums:

```
export enum EuropeanCars {
  MAKE_A = 1
  MAKE_B = 2
}

export enum AmericanCars {
  MAKE_A = 3
  MAKE_B = 4
}
```

I want to build objects and force them to have the keys of the enum type:

```
export const AmericanCarDetails: Vehicle<EuropeanCars> = {
...
}
```

Currently, I'm getting this error in the interface: `key:E --- An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) instead of interface:

```
export type Vehicle<E extends PropertyKey> = {
    [key in E]: {
        title: string
    }
}

export enum EuropeanCars {
    MAKE_A = 1,
    MAKE_B = 2
}

export enum AmericanCars {
    MAKE_A = 3,
    MAKE_B = 4
}

export const AmericanCarDetails: Vehicle<AmericanCars> = {
    [AmericanCars.MAKE_A]: { title: 'foo' },
    [AmericanCars.MAKE_B]: { title: 'foo' },
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqwAWBLAxgG2AB4BROUGYAOwBMBnOABSghVkQGlhEA+OAXjgBvAFBxxcANoBrbnGxU4JALoAuYWIlaY2GIXV0YUBQHNN4gL4irI0JFjkqAVwC2SpyxQBDKgGEvUAyiWgCyAIIcJAD6YQJwAIwANOZw4ZFRAEJxAEzWIrbg0PDUrnBhLsDGuD7+gRqhEdGxggDMyQ3pWYIALHkF9vC4EFSGZRVVNQEAIsAwXtj4dOoYOATE5ZV4k4F8gsESkhsTfgF0AHRpTWrCCLr6cADkAGYQEA9wFu0HR1sngReNTLXIS3PTAdTPV7vT7WIA)